# C++: Avoid nullptr initialization of members in constructor

Tags: c++

A class like

```
class A{
    public:

    const B& instanceOfB ;

    A(const B& someInstanceOfB):
        instanceOfB(someInstanceOfB)
    {
    };

    // some methods depending on instanceOfB here

};
```

should be extended to provide also some methods which do not depend on `instanceOfB`, and these methods must be accessible without any `instanceOfB` (i.e., no instance of `B` may exist at all).

Hence, a straight forward extension could look like

```
class A{

    public:

    B* const instanceOfB ;

    A():
    instanceOfB(nullptr)
    {
    }

    // some methods not depending on instanceOfB here

    void assignInstanceOfB(B* const someInstanceOfB){
        instanceOfB = someInstanceOfB;};

    // some methods depending on instanceOfB here

};
```

However, in my opinion, this has several disadvantages:

- The original version of the class was easy to use, while for the extended version it must be ensured that `assignInstanceOfB` is called prior to any other method depending on `instanceOfB`
- Basically, any method depending on `instanceOfB` must check if the initialization was perfomed. This produces a huge (i.e., ugly) overhead.
- A `nullptr` initialization is used, which seems to be bad practice in my opinion. I generally try to avoid *any* pointers.

So i am not really satisfied by this design. What could look a more sophisticated version look like? Thank you!

Edit: Due to the comments, i add following additional requirements:
- Splitting of the class is not possible
- The reference to B must be stored, it is not possible to hand it only to the respective methods.

To summarize, it seems that using pointers (including smart pointers) is the recommended or at least usual way.

Comment: IMHO, you should be attempting to avoid the use of _references_ as member variables, not (hopefully smart) pointers.

Comment: "This produces a huge (i.e., ugly) overhead." comparing a pointer to `nullptr` is not huge. Is it ugly? That is a matter of taste

Comment: You shouldn't use raw pointers at all. Have a look at [dynamic memory management](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), or use a reference.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That statement is too generic. Pointers not always represent ownership.

Comment: @Slava Using raw pointers is preserved for pretty much rare cases though.

Comment: How about `A::A(B* const instanceOfB =  nullptr) : instanceOfB{instanceOfB} {};`  Also your `assignInstanceOfB` won't work because `instanceOfB` is a const pointer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this one can be easily one of them

Comment: Any reason not to have `A`'s methods using the instance of `B` just receive it by `const&` as a parameter and not have the class have it as a member in the first place? This also have the advantage of delivering the intention that this method relies on this instance, as opposed to methods not taking it.

Comment: *"`class A` should be extended"*. Are you sure ? Can you split that in 2 classes or add extra layer instead ?

Answer (score 2):

To address your first concern about having to call the initialize function before the object can be used, you could implement two constuctors. One would take in a pointer to `B` and the other defaults to nulling the pointer.

```
class A{
    public:

    B* const instanceOfB ;

    A(B* const b) : instanceOfB(b) { }

    A() : A(nullptr) { }
};
```

In regards to your third concern, using non-owning pointers is the usual way to store a reference to an object that may or may not exist. If you are hell-bent on not using pointers you could use `std::optional` in a manner such as this:

```
class A
{
public:
    std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<B>> instanceOfB;

    A(B * const b = nullptr) : instanceOfB(std::nullopt)
    {
         if (b != nullptr)
         {
             instanceOfB = std::make_optional(std::ref(*b));
         }
    }

    void doSomething()
    {
        if (!instanceOfB)
        {
            return;
        }

        instanceOfB->get().something();
    }
};
```

You need to use `std::reference_wrapper` since `std::optional` explicitly does not support storing references directly. You'll still need to check if the optional contains anything before using it, so you still end up needing code that's very similar to checking for a null pointer. There's even worse syntax to access the inner reference, as can be seen in `doSomething()`. In the end this doesn't seem like it gains you anything, and I wouldn't recommend it.